# using multiple version of babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I have this in .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2015", {"modules": false}],
    "stage-2",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "react-hot-loader/babel"
  ]
}
```

but in another task I need stage-0, is it possible to create conditional case for babel? Above config is for webpack 2, unfortunately other stuff broke because it used stage-0 of babel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use webpack's `url` parameters to supply different configs to babel

Example

**webpack.prod.js**

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
      presets: [
        ["es2015", {"modules": false}],
        "stage-2",
        "react"
      ],
      plugins: [
        "react-hot-loader/babel"
      ]
    }
}
```

**webpack.stage.js**

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
      presets: [
        ["es2015", {"modules": false}],
        "stage-0",
        "stage-2",
        "react"
      ],
      plugins: [
        "react-hot-loader/babel"
      ]
    }
}
```

Reference: [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader#usage)

Hope this helps!

Comment: this is just run 2 different webpack file, I want to run npm test.